# NullPointerException on calling Activity from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity that extends FragmentActivity say MainActivity and it contained two Fragments say F1, F2. In F1 fragment, calling AsyncTask and implemented interface in MainActivity i.e., FragmentActivity. In that interface method, trying to call new activity say SecondActivity that extends Activity using below code but it throws exception.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please help.

Code
MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

// Import

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
SavePaymentInterface, GetDiscountInterface{

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static Context mContext;
    public static AppData mAppData;
    public static WebServiceFunctions Obj_WebServiceFunctions;
    public static Common obj_Common;

    //var init

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

        init();
        initView();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void init() throws NotFoundException {

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.top_portrait));

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mContext = this;

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:

            break;

        case R.id.action_print:

            showAlertDialog(mContext.getString(R.string.STR_TITLE_RECEIPT_PRINT),
                    mContext.getString(R.string.STR_MESSAGE_RECEIPT_PRINT));

            break;

        case R.id.action_more:

            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initView() {

        try {

            setupTabHost();

            setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.TAB_TICKET),
                    0);
            setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.TAB_CASHIER), 1);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@initView(): " + e.toString());
        }

        addTabListener();

    }


    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
                return m.new TicketFragment();

            default:

                MainActivity m1 = new MainActivity();
                return m1.new CashierFragment();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class TicketFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_ticket, container, false);

            //variable init

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() 
        {

            super.onResume();


        }

    }


    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class CashierFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_cashier, container, false);

            //variable init          

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // some code
                }
            });

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnValidations)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) { 

                    try {
                        new AsyncGetDiscountList(mContext, MainActivity.this,
                                Obj_WebServiceFunctions).execute();


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        LogFile.writeLOG(TAG,
                                ": " + e.toString());

                    }
                }
            });

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPayment)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) { 

                    try {

                        new AsyncSavePayment(mContext,
                                MainActivity.this,
                                Obj_WebServiceFunctions).execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, ": "
                                + e.toString());
                    }


                }

            });

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {

            super.onResume();

        }

    }

    public void showAlertDialog(String strTitle, String strMessage) {

        try {

            // some code
            txtTitle.setText(strTitle);
            txtMessage.setText(strMessage);

            Button ok = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    receiptPrint();
                }
            });


            Button cancel = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);

            cancel.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.STR_LBL_NO));
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            mDialog.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@showAlertDialog(): " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void receiptPrint() {

        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrintReceiptActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("print", isPrint); // throws nullpointer exception
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@receiptPrint(): " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentDone(String response) {

        try {

            if (response) { //condition for response validility

                isPrint = true;
                showAlertDialog(
                        mContext.getString(R.string.STR_TITLE_RECEIPT_PRINT),
                        mContext.getString(R.string.STR_MESSAGE_RECEIPT_PRINT));

            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@onPaymentDone(): " + e.toString());
        }

    }


    @Override
    public Common getCommon() {
        return obj_Common;
    }


    private void addTabListener() {

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                try {
                    if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {

                        // some code

                    } else if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1) {

                        // some code
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@addTabListener(): " + e.toString());
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void setupTabHost() {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
    }

    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, int index) {

        try {

            View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag, index);

            TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {

                    return view;
                }
            });

            mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@setupTab(): " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text,
            int index) {

        try {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.lay_tabs_bg, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
            tv.setText(text);

            if (index == 0) {
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ticket_icon, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.cashier_icon, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            return view;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LogFile.writeLOG(TAG, "@createTabView(): " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetDiscount(String response) {

        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); // throws nullpointer exception
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3678)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.vale.activity.MainActivity.receiptPrint(MainActivity.java:1093)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.vale.activity.activity.MainActivity.access$4(MainActivity.java:1075)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.vale.activity.activity.MainActivity$11.onClick(MainActivity.java:1048)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4243)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17731)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-30 17:52:21.143: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you also share your log details?

Comment: post your log details.

Comment: can you post `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @PageNotFound have mentioned that activity in manifest file.. i checked that..

Comment: `SecondACtivity`, spelling error? Should be `SecondActivity`.

Comment: its my mistake while writing this post.

Comment: Does `new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);` work?

Comment: @PageNotFound no i tried that not working... Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); also tried.. but nothing worked

Comment: maybe you should post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue without doing anything..the whole day i bang my head to find the reason of the above issue. next day i compiled the code and it runs successfully without any exception or anything. strange.. :)